# How to use readolny fields in a MVCForm in atk4?

Tags: forms, atk4

I want to have a form where user can edit some (but not all) values of some fields.
So I would need to set some fields as read only, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
$f->getElement('name')->disable();
```